# GeoJson in Leaflet, importing values to several html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geojson

Im working in a leaflet project to view GIS point data, I manage to view layers, set google tiles, but what I want is to get the attributes from the layers into several html tables, I use [leaflet sidebar plugin](https://github.com/turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/) and I inserted some tables.
So far I'm able to call Json files to appear in html tables on another projects, but I cant set it up for geojson, Ive been trying to understand the code from QGIS plugin QGIS2Web but it uses geojson as js files (var), so far I got this code, and I dont know if its better to use jquery with a geojson as var (like qgis2web) or as a geojson file

```
var map = L.map("map", {
        center: [5, 28],
        zoom: 5,
        minZoom:2,
        maxZoom:20
    }).setView([-23.7, -70.42],16);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
    }).addTo(map);

var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};

L.geoJSON(json_Obras, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }
}).addTo(map);

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.OBRA );
    }

L.geoJSON(json_Obras, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

-How can I iterate the onEachFeature function to show more values from the geojson?
-how can I translate the bindpopup function to use insert it in several html tables?
-Is there a conflict between leaflet sidebar plugin and leaflet, or some other plugins, so far I cant make them work in the same code

Thanks

Comment: loop through feature in onEachFeature function to get all the features

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I managed too loop and get the values I want from the geojson, as a table with the autolinker plugin, now im working on insert that talbe into the sidebar